# Why does every query I do on Solr fill my heap memory of 10s of MB?

Tags: java, rest, solr, cloudera, heap-memory

I'm having serious difficulty in understanding what is eating up my java heap memory everytime I call a Solr service:
In my web application I have a front-end which calls a servlet, which sends a SolrQuery with this piece of code:

```
public class SolrService extends Application {
public static String url = Config.SOLR_HOST + ":" + Config.SOLR_SERVER_PORT;
final static HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(SolrService.url+"/"+Config.SOLR_INDEX+"/"+Config.SOLR_TYPE);

//in another class
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(q); 
        query.setStart(0); 
        query.setRows(limitRows);
        query.addSortField("score", ORDER.desc);
QueryResponse response;

        response = SolrService.solr.query(query,SolrRequest.METHOD.POST);
SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
 SolrDocument doc = results.get(i);
//the response is then extracted in maps and returned
```

Everytime I do a request, my Java heap memory increases by a big jump. Here is the screen of the java heap memory at 0 queries done:
[image: this is the minimum space the Solr server takes after a fresh restart]

After 3 (three) queries
[image: The three queries called the piece of code that you saw]

After trying an `optimize` which was suggested on the admin page of the core, the heap fell by a lot: 1/10 the initial one: 
[image]

But this is not a solution (maybe temporary, but I wouldn't know how to call it; maybe via some URL?)
I've seen that forcing a maximum number of results in the query the increase in heap memory is smaller.

What can I do and where can I look?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible, that your solr cache grabs the heap?

It looks like that: increasing during the first queries and remaining unchanged after a while.

So you could run an optimize with an cache auto-warming to look, if the heap-size rises the same. And you could try to reduce your cache settings. Which is not recommended, but only to find the cause.

Take a look at this where you can find some reasons for growing heap: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#How_much_heap_space_do_I_need.3F

Comment: Thank you for yuor answer. It must be the cache, I got that much yesterday, as the heap jumps up only if I query new values, but stays the same with the old ones. It also rises less with less lines loaded (the default my colleague chose is 1,000,000).
Do you know a way to reset the cache?

Comment: If you think, my answer fits your question, please mark them as right.  Your cache-size is 1,000,000? Wow. Default is 512. There are several ways to disable cache (in your SolrConfigXml, http://yonik.com/advanced-filter-caching-in-solr/) or reset cache: autowarm=0 followed by an commit could also clear the cache. Depending on the kind of cache.

Comment: Thank you, I will update you. I'm doing it all from Java and am trying to implement the "no cache" option

Comment: I tried following the instructions given on yonik, but the {!cache=false} makes no difference. How do I call the autowarm=0?

Comment: You can set the autowarm (`autowarmCount`) parameter in your `schema.xml`https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#autowarmCount This should work, because every new search handler starts with an empty cache.